# User friendly ubuntu distribution for Old PowerBook G4 15"

Tags: powerpc

I have Mac PB G4 15" 1.5 with 512mb RAM, and need to use it office style, maybe some graphic processing but nothing fancy, I need, a user friendly distribution that could bring out the best of this nice machine.

Comment: Lubuntu or Xubuntu may suit your demands... For other desktop environments 512MB might be too less.

Answer (score 0):

Xubuntu would be best for this. Some other people have gone through it here
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1147883

I'd say download the live CD or USB and give it a try see how quick it is.